# How to find software version in a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-image

I'm trying to find a suitable docker image to host a spring application. The current stack used is openjdk 11 and Tomcat 9.

Docker hub https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated has image and I can see lot of tags. But the tags are not descriptive. Is there a way to identify if an image has a specific version version of Tomcat and Openjdk(not the oracle jdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `docker search` command from the command line which returns the description column as well for the images.

Examples:

```
docker search tomcat
NAME                          DESCRIPTION                                     STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
tomcat                        Apache Tomcat is an open source implementati…   2951                [OK]
tomee                         Apache TomEE is an all-Apache Java EE certif…   86                  [OK]
dordoka/tomcat                Ubuntu 14.04, Oracle JDK 8 and Tomcat 8 base…   55                                      [OK]
bitnami/tomcat                Bitnami Tomcat Docker Image                     37                                      [OK]
kubeguide/tomcat-app          Tomcat image for Chapter 1                      29
consol/tomcat-7.0             Tomcat 7.0.57, 8080, "admin/admin"              18                                      [OK]

docker search tomcat9
NAME                                    DESCRIPTION                                     STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
kikov79/tomcat9                         Ubuntu 14.04, Oracle JDK 8 and Tomcat 9 base…   4                                       [OK]
oupula/tomcat9_jdk8                     apache tomcat 9.0.13 + jdk1.8.0_191 + tomcat…   2
zzjhacn/tomcat9jdk8                     tomcat9 with oracle jdk8 on Alpine (78M)        2                                       [OK]
donglsheng/tomcat9_jdk8                 jdk8 tomat9                                     1
ykaj9758/tomcat9                        tomcat9                                         1
utmstack/tomcat9-omp-war2safe           tomcat9-omp-war2safe                            0


docker search tomcat9jdk11
NAME                            DESCRIPTION         STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
aptea/tomcat9jdk11                                  0
binbin0915/tomcat9jdk11                             0
kapitanmf/tomcat9jdk11partner                       0
kapitanmf/tomcat9jdk11                              0
```

Note: The description column is not set for all of the images though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `docker image inspect <image_sha>` and there should be version of application I did it for artifactory and there is a key named
`ARTIFACTORYVERSION=7.39.4`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).